# angularjs angular-google-chart, remove the percent from the tooltip of piechart

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I use angularjs and angular-google-chart directive to make PieChart.

This is a working* example on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MA4cWe5XaP1hjtLUfxvI?p=preview)

[image]
The A pie is with true data but i want to render something like B pie because I have on element ('mnhn') who have 99% of the data and the others elements are almost unselecteable on hover.

This is A pie rows data :

```
var rows =[
    {"c":[{"v":"mnhn"},{"v":6311883}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"um2"},{"v":36042}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"mhnaix"},{"v":25346}]},
    ...
];
```

This is B pie rows data

```
// the only change is that i divided the value for "mnhn" by 15 and add the "f" property
var rows =[
    {"c":[{"v":"mnhn"},{"v":420792.2,"f":6311883}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"um2"},{"v":36042,"f":36042}]},
    {"c":[{"v":"mhnaix"},{"v":25346,"f":25346}]},
    ...
]
```

Now the chart use the "v" property to calculate the percent but it also display this (wrong) percent on the tooltip on hover. I want to remove the percent from the tooltip or replace it by the "f" property (which can be a percent that i calculate).

Using **"tooltip": {'text' : 'value' }** with "f" property make the google-chart.js crash.

Any advice please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
The plunckr was updated too.

```
var rows =[
{"c":[{"v":"mnhn"},{"v":420792.2,"f":"6311883"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"um2"},{"v":36042,"f":"36042"}]},
{"c":[{"v":"mhnaix"},{"v":25346,"f":"25346"}]},
...
```

]

It display only the "f" value with the option **"tooltip": {'text' : 'value'}**. In the rows data the field "f" MUST BE A STRING TO WORK PROPERLY or the code crash. take 2 days to found it...